# Using Less, can I use the current value in a @media section?

Tags: css, less

I have the following Less code:

```
@appbar-padding: 10px;

.container {
  padding-bottom: @appbar-padding + 10;
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .container {
      padding-bottom: @appbar-padding + 20;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to take the current value of the `padding-bottom` in the `@media` part? So I could do something like:

```
@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .container {
        padding-bottom: @this + 10;
    }
}
```

This way, if I change the "normal" `.container` rules to, say, `@appbar-padding + 20`, the rules for screens bigger than 750px wide will, in effect, have `@appbar-padding + 30` instead of `+ 20`.

Comment: Nope, not possible. You would have to use variables like you are doing now only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Harry, you have to pass through an intermediate variable. An example of code could be:

```
@appbar-padding: 10px;

@default-padding:@appbar-padding + 10;

.container {
  padding-bottom: @default-padding;
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .container {
      padding-bottom: @default-padding + 20;
    }
}
```

The idea is to pre-define "*default*" (what you call "normal") value for padding, that is calculated starting by `@appbar-padding` and then apply it to `.container`.

In Media query, this "*default*" value is what you change again. In this way, you can simulate your desired behaviour.

**NOTE**: you must declare `@default-padding:@appbar-padding + 10;` outside `.container` class definition because of [scope](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-scope).